# How to pass a Generic method to another one as Action<T> parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action

I have a generic method like this-

```
public static void GenericMethod<T1,T2>(SomeType typeObj, List<T1> entities) where T2 : SomeEntity
{
}
```

And I'd like to pass this method to another one as Action. Like this-

```
public void CallingMethod(type1 value1, type2 value, Action<???> method)
{
}
```

I can't figure out how to write the Action parameter. Any help please? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

erm,

```
public void CallingMethod(
        type1 value1,
        type2 value,
        Action<SomeType, List<type1>> method)
{
}
```

presumably but, you don't make what you want to achieve clear in your question.

---

If you want to accept some undefined generic action, then the method you call will need generic type parameters.

```
public void CallingMethod<T1>(
        type1 value1,
        type2 value,
        Action<SomeType, List<T1>> method)
{
}
```

Comment: No dude, your solution works for non-generic methods. How about passing a Generic one? What kind of clarification you need?

Comment: @AnirbanBose, I need this kind of clarification and, probably more.